# ionic cordova platform add android Error: Unexpected close tag error

Tags: cordova, ionic3

I am new on ionic 3. When I am trying to add platform its showing the following error:

```
arun@arun-HP-Laptop-15-bs1xx:~/Desktop/myApp$ ionic cordova platform add android
Error: Unexpected close tag
Line: 83
Column: 9
Char: >``
    at error (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:666:10)
    at strictFail (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:692:7)
    at closeTag (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:885:9)
    at SAXParser.write (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:1436:13)
    at XMLParser.feed (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/elementtree/lib/parsers/sax.js:48:15)
    at ElementTree.parse (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/elementtree/lib/elementtree.js:271:10)
    at Object.parse (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/elementtree/lib/elementtree.js:584:8)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-utils/lib/cordova/config.js:35:28)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:104:62)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared the relevant code

Comment: check your config.xml for possible syntax errors? Did you happen to edit it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your config.xml, dont forget put backslash at end of every tag.